# Eclipse CDT and Compiling C++ Templates

Tags: c++, templates, build, eclipse-cdt

I have a very basic system I'm using to learn C++ templates. My understanding is that one should include the template definition in the template declaration file and compile that instead of the implementation, like so:

```
/*LINKEDLIST.H*********************************/

#ifndef LINKEDLIST_H_
#define LINKEDLIST_H_

#include "node.h"

template <typename T>
class linkedlist {
    /*..*/
};

#include "linkedlist.tpp"

/*LINKEDLIST.TPP*********************************/

#include "node.h"

template<typename T>
linkedlist<T>::linkedlist() {
    /*..*/
}
```

How can I get Eclipse CDT to compile the header files for the templates? It seems to be attempting to compile the template files themselves and giving me `linker input file unused because linking not done` errors.

```
Building file: ../linkedlist.tpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"linkedlist.d" -MT"linkedlist.d" -o "linkedlist.o" "../linkedlist.tpp"
g++.exe: warning: ../linkedlist.tpp: linker input file unused
```

I can write my own makefile, but I'm interested to see if there's a solution to this in the IDE.

Answer (score 2):

You don't build the `.tpp` files. They are only included in the header files with the `#include` directive.

Instead you include the header file in a proper `.cpp` source file.

Comment: I know, but by default Eclipse CDT tries to build the .tpp files - how can I make it build the corresponding .h instead?

Comment: @Thomas Doesn't Eclipse keep sources and headers in separate "folders" in the project? Make sure the ".tpp" is not in the `Sources` "folder" and that it is in the `Headers` "folder".

Comment: everything is in one directory at the moment. I have resorted to a make file, and I'm finding g++ is compiling the template headers into precompiled headers of ~6MB. Any ideas?

Comment: @Thomas I'm not talking about a physical directory on the disk, but a folder in the project tree in Eclipse. But also in a Makefile the `.tpp` file should be handled like a header file.

Comment: When you say the .tpp should be handled like a .h in the make file, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: @Thomas If, in your makefile, you have a variable `HEADERS` that lists all header files and a variable `SOURCES` that lists all source files, then the `.tpp` file should be listed in `HEADERS` and _not_ `SOURCES`. The same for Eclipse (or most of any other IDE), where in the project tree have a folder (not on disk but in the tree-view control listing all your files) called something like `Headers` and one something like `Sources`. The `.tpp` file should be in `Headers` and _not_ `Sources`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17297/discussion-between-thomas-and-joachim-pileborg)

Answer (score 1):

Your .tpp files are associated as C++ **Source** Files instead of C++ **Template** Files. To fix this:

Go into the Eclipse Preferences Window.

C/C++ -> File Types

In column Filename, find an extension with tpp in it (most likely *.tpp) and remove it.

Click New...

Pattern: *.tpp
Type: C++ **Header** File